# Can ReSharper autocomplete closing brace for a selection?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, resharper, textselection

Very often I need to enclose a selected piece of text or anything else with braces:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit met.
     [-----] <- selection
```

but when I hit for example `{` the selectecd text is replaced with the `{` instead. However I'd like it to be enclosed with `{}` like:

```
Lorem {ipsum} dolor sit met.
```

Is it possible to do with `ReSharper v9`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, in case of *text* selection it is possible to do with `Surround Templates` called by `Alt+Enter` (Visual Studio keyboard scheme). ReSharper has built-in template for braces: `{}`. It places the braces on separate lines, so in your case better to define custom template in `Tools -> Templates Explorer`. It's easy, you need to add something like `{$SELECTION$}` in template definition and it will be *inline*.

P.S. R# If you select *code*, not a *text piece* inside a string definition, then  R# prevents braces placing on the same line. So custom *inline* template will not work in code case.

Comment: I know VS templates and I even created my own but I've never come up to the idea to look at the `Surround Templates`, how embarassing. I'll try it out. ;-) Thanks.

Comment: I got it ;-) I edited the default `{}` `Surround Template` and removed the line breaks, then I disabled the `Reformat` option and `R#` doesn't add any line breaks anymore. Now I just need to repeat it for `()` and `[]`.

Comment: @t3chb0t, interesting, I was sured that `Reformat` option doesn't change braces position, thanks! Also there is a lot of brace auto-format options in R#, so the formatting may work unexpectingly sometimes. These settings may be easily filtered by promting "brace" in R# `Options` searchbox.